# How to write logs to cloudwatch in .net

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

Please provide me sample application to write logs to cloudwatch in c#, i tried https://github.com/aws/aws-logging-dotnet, doesnot get any help from that.

Comment: SO is for programming questions. Not for asking where to find sample applications or asking people to write you one.

Comment: Anything is fine.

Comment: I got the answer, it can be done by using cloudwatch agent and it requires configuration changes, once the configuration changes are done it allows you write into logs.

Answer (score 4):

The AWS documentation for C# is very good. Here is an article [specifically about logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/dotnet-logging.html).

Basically, the short of it is anything written to Standard Out or Standard Error will write to the logs, such as `Console.WriteLine("Some text");`

Additionally, with lambda functions, the context contains a static logger that can be used with `context.Logger.Log("Write this to log");`

I suggest taking some time and giving the documentation a good read and working with their examples, which are also very good.

Comment: From my experience , the former doesn't write immediately to the log , while the latter write immediately ( no buffer)

Comment: Thanks for you effort, i got answer with zero code changes, only thing is need to do some configuration changes.